# How do I convert a time from one timezone to another using Luxon

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone, luxon

I have a time from the server with returns

```
2022-10-16T13:17:05.885+00:00
```

The time zone is 'Asia/Manila'. This time represents October 16, 2022, 9:17pm

I want to convert this time to be read as October 16, 2022, 9:17pm, or the same as 'Asia/Manila'  even if the client computer is of different time zone, e.g. 'Asia/Tokyo' or any other time zone automatically.

Here's what I have tried so far.

1. Convert Asia Manila Time to UTC

   ```
   const utcDate = DateTime.fromISO('2022-10-16T13:17:05.885+00:00').toUTC().toISO();
   ```
2. Convert UTC Date to Client timezone:

   ```
   const convertedDate = DateTime.fromISO(utcDate).setZone('Australia/Darwin');
   ```

The converted date returns: October 16, 2022, 10:47 PM
My desired result is October 16, 2022, 9:17pm or the same time as it is in the 'Asia/Manila'

I am using Luxon and I haven't figured it out yet for months searching for answers

Comment: As already stated by others, since input time contains `+00:00` it represent a time in UTC not in Asia/Manila.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you are looking for,

```
const date = DateTime.fromISO('2022-10-16T13:17:05.885+00:00').setZone('Asia/Manila');
```

output,

```
2022-10-16T21:17:05.885+08:00
```

Comment: The time 2022-10-16T13:17:05.885+00:00 is already at timezone 'Asia/Manila', when the client computer is using timezone example: 'Asia/Srednekolymsk' or 'Australia/Darwin', both should be able to return October 16, 2022, 9:17pm or the same time as it is in the original timezone

Comment: 2022-10-16T13:17:05.885+00:00 this is in UTC not 'Asia/Manila' timezone. So you have to convert this to 'Asia/Manila' timezone. So for example: 'Asia/Srednekolymsk' or 'Australia/Darwin' will see October 16, 2022, 9:17pm.

Comment: 2022-10-16T13:17:05.885+00:00 is 'Asia/Manila' time zone. That is my time zone. That is the time generated from the server

Comment: frankly, when +00:00 is added to the end of the time, it is UTC.